Middleware to have one user using its own database
I'm starting a SaaS and to avoid having a too big database, and to help for debugging, I would like each user to use its own database, without duplicating the laravel app.
I have been suggesting using a middleware who switches to the user database, depending on the route (for other routes like authentication, profile edging, all users will use the same common database).
Here i my middleware :
class DatabaseSwitcher
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
      
         if (Auth::check())
         {
         
            $user = Auth::user();

            if ($user->email === 'user1@a.com') // example
            {
                Log::info('Current database connection: ' . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName());

                // Use a specific  database for this user
                Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'xbot_user1');

                Log::info('Current database connection: ' . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName());

               DB::purge('mysql'); // this line cause an exception 

                Log::info('Current database connection: ' . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName());

               $connection = DB::connection('mysql');

                   if (!$connection) {
                    throw new \Exception("Failed to establish a database connection.");
                }

                   DB::reconnect('mysql'); // Reconnecte avec la nouvelle configuration

                   Log::info('Current database connection: ' . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName());

            }

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}

Because of DB::purge('mysql');  I got :
Call to a member function prepare() on null {"userId":22,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function prepare() on null at /home/nicolas/Desktop/projets-web/twitterbot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:592)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/nicolas/Desktop/projets-web/twitterbot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(812): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->Illuminate\\Database\\{closure}()

What is really weird, is when I remove the purge function, I don't have the exception, bubDB::connection()->getDatabaseName())  return the previous database, so it seems the database is not switched, BUT in my view, when I display data fetched with eloquent, data from the user database are returned).
So it seems it did not use the same database returned by DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
By the way, is it a good way to do it? Or is there any better way? I'm sure that big SaaS do not have all their users using the same database.
Thanks

You use this method to communicate with the database: =>
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::connection()->setDatabaseName('xbot_user1');
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::connection()->setDatabaseName('xbot_user2');
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();

If your need is solved, leave a comment and confirm so that I can record the answer.

Make sure the mysql connection configuration and make sure it is connected to the mysql service.

DB_HOST,DB_PORT,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD

I had to use files for session to make it works.
in .env file :
SESSION_DRIVER=file
instead of
SESSION_DRIVER=database
